# Eclipse IDE problem "not win32 application"

Tags: eclipse, ide, windows-xp, installation

I downloaded Eclipse from some Asian university mirror, then tried to install it, but got error:

> [path]\eclipse.exe is not win32 application

In file `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M
-showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
--launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrupt download, probably. Or a 32/64 bit issue (this is suggestive that at least some of what it's trying is 64 bit: "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64")?

Which version did you download? What mirror and what file from that mirror did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the 64 bit version, and you try to run on 32 bit windows.